# nmap configuration file

Tags: linux, networking, nmap, linuxmint

I'm running Linux mint and I need to modify my nmap configuration's default service enumeration by making a new service list.  I think I do this in the config file (I'm not positive), but I can't seem to find an nmap config file.  I know the services I need to run, and the service flags, I just need a way to configure what nmap does by default.  I've tried looking everywhere I can think of, and I've found some files in /usr/share/nmap, but none of them seem to be config files.  Once again, I know the command I want run including the flags and services, I just need a way to edit the default configuration.  Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use numbers to tell nmap which ports to use?

Comment: What specific actions do you need to configure? What can't be done from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nmap does some things by default (TCP SYN scan, reverse (PTR) DNS name resolution) but most other functions are specified with command-line flags. That said, there are some [configuration files](http://nmap.org/book/data-files.html) that affect how Nmap works.

From your question, I guess the file you're interested in is [`nmap-services`](http://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html). This file follows the same structure as the [Unix services file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/services.5.html), with an additional column for an empirical "open-frequency" score, based on Internet-wide scans conducted by the Nmap development team. The default Nmap port scan scans the top 1000 most-frequently-open ports, based on this file. The SERVICE column in Nmap's output is populated from the first column in this file, unless overridden by service version detection results.

Answer (score 0):

The default service definition on *NIX is in `/etc/services`, which is usually shipped by your distribution and not by nmap.